# Rails: Connect to MS SQL on flex server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have ms sql installed on my FLEX server. Would like to know the connectivity details on how to establish connection from my rails application to the ms sql resting on flex ?

Is it the same like any other connection ?

Comment: what is a FLEX server? Can't find in Google as well

Answer (score 0):

Some people have recommended this gem for connecting to MS SQL server:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds